# slow video playing

Tags: video, video-player

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop. However, video are not playing in smooth but videos in youtue and other website play without any problem. Can anyone give an advice?

And also I tried the `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`it didn't work on by the way my linux version is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: You haven't provided any clues as to which video software you're talking about.. is it `mpv`, `vlc` or another choice?  have you tried other players?   Also specifics of your video hardware may also be useful (`sudo lshw -C video` maybe) but there are many reasons for issues, and knowing what software you are asking about is a starting point at least.

Comment: Yeah I only tried mpv and vlc  could you please recommend a player

Comment: I don't know what you've tried... the two I mentioned I personally prefer to `totem`, but this is not a forum (https://ubuntuforums.org/ is that), this is a Q&A site where you provide your question, by comment we ask you to complete any *unspecified* or vague details & then people can write answers.  opinion is not on-topic here (that belongs on forums).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to fix this problem first you install h.264 decorder for your system to do this use `sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav` after that you have to install totem player for your ubuntu `sudo apt-get install totem` you can run this for to this problem